# Can't changes Facecolor. What's the problem?

Tags: materials

I'm a big blender newby that's why I can't handle this little problem by myself..
I've just finished my retopology of a model and now I simply wanted to change the color of the faces by selecting them and assign it.

But it doesn't work. With my last model, there was a Option in the Material Menu where you could simply change the color with a Dropdown-Menu called "Diffuse". But this time there is no Diffuse Menu.

All I have is this Diffuse BSDF Option. But it doesn't change anything.
Could anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance! :)

[image]

Comment: Switch to *Edit Mode*, then the *Assign* button should appear. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Damn.. I'm just dumb as fuck.. just realized I needed to switch to Blender Render to get the Diffuse Menu..